# RxJava - Continue a concat after giving an Exception

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to run 2 observables sequentially although, if the first one gives a specific error I would like to stop the concat and execute another thing.

Despite, the first observable might giving many exceptions, I just want to stop propagating the concat when a specific error is reached (in this case HttpException 403), on the other hand I want to proceed with the concat execution when there isn't any 403 HttpException.

I've done the following code, but so far I cannot proceed the concat execution with replacing the current observable to Observable.error(throwable).

Is there a method to do it without changing the observable logic or the subscriber logic?
Or something to stop propagating a concat on a specific error, and continue if other error is given?

```
 Observable.concat(getObservable1(), getObservable2())
                    .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends OperationModel>>() {
                                @Override
                                public Observable<? extends OperationModel> call(Throwable throwable) {
                                    if(throwable instanceof HttpException && ((HttpException)throwable).code() == 403) {
                                            return Observable.error(throwable);
                                    }
                                     return Observable.empty(); //here I just want to proceed the concat despite giving an error
                                }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //execute requests should be on io() thread
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
                    .subscribe(new CustomRequestSubscriber<>());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
Observable.concat(getObservable1().onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends OperationModel>>() {
                                @Override
                                public Observable<? extends OperationModel> call(Throwable throwable) {
                                    if(throwable instanceof HttpException && ((HttpException)throwable).code() == 403) {
                                            return Observable.error(throwable);
                                    }
                                     return Observable.empty(); //here I just want to proceed the concat despite giving an error
                                }), getObservable2())

                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //execute requests should be on io() thread
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
                    .subscribe(new CustomRequestSubscriber<>());
```

This should catch the error in the first observable, and then you can continue with the second observable.

Comment: I was stating to questioning the whole onErrorResumeNext(). Thanks that works! :)

Comment: Thanks. I was using onErrorReturn in my scenario but the above was helpful. Upvote.